# Change style of time picker in primeng calendar

Tags: css, angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm trying to remove the padding and set the font style to smaller in the time-picker used in primeng calendar for angular 7.

```
<p-calendar [ngModel]="xxx" timeOnly="true" [(hourFormat)]="hourFormat" [(dateFormat)]="timeFormat" [showIcon]="false"
  [style]="{'display':'initial'}" [inputStyle]="{'border-width':'1px 1px 1px 1px', 'width':'100%','height':'25px'}"></p-calendar>
```

but it's not applying.

[image]

this is the rendered html class for that box

```
class="ui-timepicker ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ng-tns-c9-1 ng-star-inserted"
```

I tried

```
::ng-deep .ui-timepicker .ui-widget-header{
padding:initial;
font-size:smaller;
}
```

and

```
::ng-deep .ui-timepicker.ui-widget-header{
padding:initial;
font-size:smaller;
}
```

Doesn't work. any leads would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::ng-deep .ui-timepicker.ui-widget-header{
  padding:initial;
  font-size:smaller;
}
```

actually works, font is smaller, but the padding is still same, because primeng has:

```
body .ui-datepicker .ui-timepicker {
    border: 0 none;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8dae2;
    padding: 0.857em;
}
```

which has higher specifity than your style.

You can increase the specifity for your style:

```
::ng-deep div.ui-datepicker .ui-timepicker{
  padding:initial;
  font-size:smaller;
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bzdhvr)